# Hazelcast and Akka is it good idea

Tags: akka, hazelcast

Reading this post [Hazelcast with Akka and Spray](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/hazelcast-spray-akka). I wonder would be corrent to say that:

It is NOT good idea to use actor here because it would slow down the system due to sequential `put()` (?)

As I understand `hazelcast` `put()` and `get()` may work much faster if it was not inside actor. Hazelcast uses blocking/async Map as a storage, but it blocks by key but not entier map object. But actor makes it/puts sequential, so there is no way to put sevarlal `put(key,value)` one should wait for the next one in the actor's queue. With no actor this two puts could happans in parrallel.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

We may think about put/get as of beeing blocking/long operations since hazelcast works in clusters, so it is not as fast as just plain memory map. But if having more than one actors to makes it faster then we should think about locking if two actors tryng to add same `(key,value)` pair as we would not having actors. Having *pool of actors*.. leads to idea not using actors at all in this scenario. (?)

We indeed may have many reader actors, but even without `actor`-involvment we could read from hazelcast map from all N threads simulanuisly (again: assuming that `get` may take some time due to 'blocking'/'long-living' nature of it in hazelcast).

To make a quesion of it:
**Q:** Does it make sense to use Actor(s) wrappaing `hazelcast` in it?

Comment: wondering if you figured out new pros/cons with this approach? thanks

Comment: what i figured at that time is: ether use actor based cash-solution or hazel-cast without actor. I mean hazelcast case does its own concurrency-handling.

Comment: sorry for being late to party. I have a question: Can't we just use Akka Clustering + Actor Sharding. We can make use of "Remember Entities" which will mean that all the data pertaining to actors are always saved in-memory. This would allow for faster processing(avoiding round trip to Database). Is HazelCast providing something more than what Akka ecosystem is already providing?